# difficulties setting the Blueimp Photo Gallary

Tags: javascript, html, css, blueimp

I know that stackOverflow already has many questions about Blueimp Photo Gallary, but my problem is so basic that I couldn't find an answer, that's why I came asking.

I can't set the Blueimp, I already followed the github's steps but it doesn't work at all. Besides that I would like to get the images url from my flickr, is that possible? I think it is but I don't know how.

I would be really glad if someone could help me out.

Thanks a lot.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!--[if IE]>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<![endif]-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>blueimp Gallery</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueimp/blueimp-gallery.min.css">

<script>
document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
        link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
        options = {index: link, event: event},
        links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
        blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
};
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <!-- The Gallery as lightbox dialog, should be a child element of the document body -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
    <div class="slides"></div>
    <h3 class="title"></h3>
    <a class="prev">‹</a>
    <a class="next">›</a>
    <a class="close">×</a>
    <a class="play-pause"></a>
    <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>

<div id="links">
    <a href="img/surf/1.jpg" title="Banana">
        <img src="img/surf/1.jpg" alt="Banana">
    </a>
    <a href="img/surf/1.jpg" title="Banana">
        <img src="img/surf/1.jpg" alt="Banana">
    </a>
    <a href="img/surf/1.jpg" title="Banana">
        <img src="img/surf/1.jpg" alt="Banana">
    </a>
</div>

</body> 
<script src="js/blueimp/blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Load **jquery** before blueimp-gallery.js.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/blueimp/blueimp-gallery.min.js"></script>
```

And check Chrome console for any errors.